# Converting Affymetrix (*_at) Mouse Probe ID to HUGO gene symbol in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have the following list of probes (from Mouse),

```
1460644_at
1460645_at
1460646_at
1460647_a_at
1460648_at
1460649_at
1460650_at
1460651_at
1460652_at
1460653_at
1460654_at
1460655_a_at
1460656_a_at
1460657_at
1460658_at
1460659_at
1460660_x_at
1460661_at
```

The longer list can be found here: http://dpaste.com/1371949/plain/

What I want to do is to convert that name with gene Symbol using R.
What's the way to do it?

I tried this but failed

```
#source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("hgu95av2.db")
# biocLite("affy")
library(hgu95av2.db)
library(affy)
dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1371949/plain/")
probes<-as.vector(as.matrix(dat))
Symbols = unlist(mget(probes, hgu95av2SYMBOL, ifnotfound=NA))
# all returns NA
```

**Update**: I tried BioMart but no avail:

```
library(biomaRt)
dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1371949/plain/")
probes<-as.vector(as.matrix(dat))
mouse = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
g = getGene( id = probes, type = "affy_mg_u74av2", mart = mouse)
show(g)
```

It prints Ensembl gene id instead (e.g.ENSMUSG00000057666)

Comment: biomaRt should work http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/biomaRt.html

Comment: It has the Ensembl ID and the gene name, no? g$mgi_symbol

Comment: Please do not post questions here and at the same time on the [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/); you'll get an answer on one forum and waste people's time on the other. Ask in one place only.

Comment: use `getBM` method and set the right attributes (`listAttributes(mart)`) and filter (`listFilters(mart)`)